# How do i retain form data when doing a page lookup

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to do a table lookup. I fill out the fields then click the combobox to do a lookup. When I return to the page, the Last Name Field goes blank. I need a way of keeping the field Data when I return to the page.

```
<?php /*?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['First'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['First']); }?>
<?php */?>

<tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Last Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" autofocus value="" placeholder="last name" size="32" /></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">City:</td>
    <td>
        <select name="LookupCity" id="LookupCity">
            <option value="" 
                <?php if (!(strcmp("", $_GET['City']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>
                Select from menu
            </option>
            <?php do { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_fmCity['City']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_fmCity['City'], $_GET['City']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_fmCity['City']?>
            </option>
            <?php
                } while ($row_fmCity = mysql_fetch_assoc($fmCity));
                $rows = mysql_num_rows($fmCity);
                if($rows > 0) {
                    mysql_data_seek($fmCity, 0);
                    $row_fmCity = mysql_fetch_assoc($fmCity); 
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <a href="ZipLookup.php?Last Name=<?php echo $Last_Name ?>">select</a>
    </td>
```

Please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the "value" attribute of the controls.

Comment: Please give an example..I don't understand

Comment: For example, change

`<td><input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" autofocus value="" placeholder="last name" size="32" /></td>`

to

`<td><input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" autofocus value="<?php if($_POST['Last_Name']) echo $_POST['Last_Name']; ?>" placeholder="last name" size="32" /></td>`

Comment: Its not working..I guess because i'm not posting...When i return to page the last Name field returns blank.

Comment: You must pass the variables to the page in some way, either with $_GET or $_SESSION

Comment: Can you please give an example..i'm so new at this and its driving me nuts...thanks

Comment: You just go `session_start();` in site with processing and in site with form, then in processing do `$_SESSION['form'] = $_POST;` and then set the value to `$_SESSION['form']['Last_Name']`

Comment: I did this and still don’t work session_start();
$_SESSION['form'] = $_POST;
<input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" autofocus value="<?php $_SESSION['form']['Last_Name'] ?>" placeholder="last name" size="32" />

Comment: You must do this `session_start(); $_SESSION['form'] = $_POST;` in PHP code. It seems that you are new to PHP, maybe you should try to do some lessons first?

Comment: could it not be working because im not posting..i'm linking to another page, grabbing info and returning to page,,,but not posting.

Comment: So, pass it in get when redirecting (when you redirect to index.php?foo=bar, then you can recall it with $_GET['foo'])